# Glow effect on Button on pressed?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

Is there any way to add a glow effect on a Qt button so that only appears when clicked?

For now I am using a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` for the glow effect and I do not know any thing better for it; if there's something better please tell me. The problem is this effect is always showing not just on clicks.

Is there any way to do is so that it is done when clicked and preferably with QSS and stylesheets but effects are also valid?

```
self.shadow2 = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
self.shadow2.setBlurRadius(5)
self.shadow2.setXOffset(6)
self.shadow2.setYOffset(6)
self.button1.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
```

Comment: QSS doesn't provide any of that, and can only be done programmatically. Depending on the effect you want, you could just connect the click signal of the button with [`setEnabled()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html#enabled-prop), possibly with an animation or a timer to disable the effect again. If you want more help, please show us your attempt in form of a [mre].

Comment: Thank you i have added the code, if i was to use this method, would i need to do an individual effect on all the elements in the widget

Comment: What I meant in my previous comment is that you should try to achieve what explained, and, if you don't succeed, then provide the code for those attempts. And, yes, you probably need to create a graphics effect for each element, so it's probably better to create a subclass of the button and use that every where you want it

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `setStyleSheet` for this.

```
self.button1.setStyleSheet(
    """QPushButton::clicked{css code for color,shadow or anything visual}"""
)
```